# Changing wordpress posts URL

Tags: wordpress, url, permalinks

I have a wordpress website with bunch of posts. My problem is that I need to change the URLs from

```
website.com/post-name
```

to

```
website.com/specialword/post-name
```

The "specialword" is what I need to add in front of those post names, but ONLY for the post type - posts.

Can someone help me?

I need this badly, mostly because of the SEO purposes so I can keep the URLs from the previous website that wasn't done in wordpress.

Thank you!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

- Go to Settings -> Permalinks
- Select Custom Structure
- Fill in with /specialword/%postname%

Screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Oh come on guys, I wrote "but ONLY for the post type - posts".

Comment: Actually pages keep their permalinks intact (eg: http://localhost/wordpress/about-page), while posts will use the new permalinks (eg: http://localhost/wordpress/specialword/testing-posts).

Just tested before submitting my answer.

Comment: This answer is incorrect, as this affects custom post types, not just the "posts" post type.

Comment: Actually, not really. For new custom post types, you declare slug to use, ex for a "book" post types, you would use: 'rewrite'            => array( 'slug' => 'book' ),

Answer (score 1):

To have "/specialword/" appear in the "post" (blog) url, you need to set "Custom Structure" in permalinks to "/specialword/%postname%".

Then, to NOT have /specialword/ appear in a custom post type url, you need to set "with_front" to false when registering the custom post type, like this:

```
"rewrite" => [ "slug" => "myposttype", "with_front" => false ]
```